# d3: import JSON locally while keeping the data separate from my SVG creation

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

In wishing to keep my data separate from my visual I want to break away from the d3 norm of the following.

```
d3.json("data/2014/adopted.json", function (d) {
   // make an interesting visualization and put all of my code here
});
```

Instead I wish to bring my data in to my script so I could interact with it.

```
myData = d3.json("data/2014/adopted.json", function (d) {
    console.log(d);
    return d;
});
```

My goal is to have an object my code can interact with.  The console.log() works but when I try to return d, it is undefined.

```
myData[0] //Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
```

I wish to work with data like when I include it as a variable in my script.  I could do this with my current code but I wish to grow past that.  How can I make myData into an object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The d3.json API call does not return a value as you expect. I cannot find documentation to specify what is the return of the d3.json method is. From your example, it seems always return a undefined value.

You could do it like this:

```
var jsondata;
d3.json(dataPath, function(dataFromServer) {
  jsondata = dataFromServer;
}
```

Comment: thank you for your comment.  I missed that very easy solution.  I tried that out and it does exactly what I need.  Thank you Huan!

Comment: I'd be surprised if this wouldn't log `undefined` since you're setting the variable in the callback, which happens after the log statement.

Comment: @mgold Thanks for pointing that, the log sentence has been removed.